# Update a listbox from another listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have two Winforms (admForm and projForm) and each have a listbox. Inside the admForm you can add a user in the list box that belongs to this form.

Everything works fine so far, but I would like to update the listbox in "projForm" with objects that are in the list box in "admForm".

Any idea?

In admForm:

```
public string ListBox
{
    get { return lstUserOrProject.Items.ToString(); }
}
```

In projForm:

```
private void UpdateList()
{
    AdminForm admForm = new AdminForm();
    lstAvailableUser.Items.Add(admForm.ListBox.ToString());
}
```

Code to open the projForm:

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = lstUserOrProject.SelectedIndex;

        switch (cmbUserOrProject.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case (int)UserOrProject.Projects:
                ProjectForm proj = new ProjectForm("Add Project");

                if (proj.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    projMngr.AddProject(proj.ProjectData);
                    UpdateProject();
                }
                break;

            case (int)UserOrProject.Users:
                UserForm user = new UserForm("Add User");


                if (user.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    userMngr.AddUser(user.UserData);
                    UpdateUser();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the relationship between these two forms? They are both displayed togheter? One form opens the other?

Comment: Yes, inside admForm you can open projForm. You can also inside admForm add a user that shows in a list inside admForm.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
AdminForm admForm = new AdminForm();
```

You are creating completely new instance.

If you are open your projForm after your AdminForm, when you are showing your form use this code:

```
ProjForm projForm = new ProjForm();  // change ProjForm if your form class name is different
projForm.Show(this);
```

Then in your projForm you can access your listBox like this:

```
private void UpdateList()
{
  var items = Owner.lstUserOrProject.Items; // Owner represents your admin form
  lstAvailableUser.Items.Clear();

   foreach(var item in items)
   {
      lstAvailableUser.Items.Add(item);
   }
 }
```

Update:

Move this definition to the top of your page in AdminForm, i mean:

```
class AdminForm : Form
{
   // move your definition here
   ProjForm projForm = new ProjForm();  // change ProjForm if your form class name is different
}
```

Then when you want to show your form call:

```
projForm.Show(this);
```

When you want to update your list in the projform call your update method:

```
projForm.UpdateList();
```

Comment: I got two error message then:
Member AdminForm.ListBox.get' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead 

An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'KanBanBoard.AdminForm.lstUserOrProject'

Comment: Uhm, what do you suppose the `lstUserOrProject.Items.ToString(); ` returns?

Comment: excuse me but I'm new at this, imagine that it should return the items in the listbox?

Comment: No, absolutely no, assuming that we are talking of WinForms ListBox, the Items property is an ObjectCollection. Applying ToString to an ObjectCollection returns "System.Windows.Forms.ListBox+ObjectCollection"

Comment: So I should not have my property?

Comment: Yes, you don't need it

Comment: ahh, with this code I can run the program. But there comes an error message when I click on the button that will show projForm: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: `private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
int index = lstUserOrProject.SelectedIndex;

switch (cmbUserOrProject.SelectedIndex)
{
case (int)UserOrProject.Projects:
ProjectForm proj = new ProjectForm("Add Project");
                    
if (proj.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
projMngr.AddProject(proj.ProjectData);
UpdateProject();
}
break;

case (int)UserOrProject.Users:
UserForm user = new UserForm("Add User");
                    
                    
if (user.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
userMngr.AddUser(user.UserData);
UpdateUser();
}
break;
}
}`